# Cannot choose to do billing on org level showing "Only projects are selectable" warning message for GCP billing

Tags: mongodb, gcp

My clients have an org setup with a folder and multiple projects in it. They want to subscribe to MongoDB Atlas via market place for their projects. When choosing the resource to tie to the subscription, GCP isn't allowing to choose the org and shows a warning message "Only projects are selectable"

[image: Warning mssg]

I thought maybe it was a permissions issue but the clients have already checked user roles and applied the following permissions:

1. Billing Account Administrator,
2. Folder Administrator,
3. Organization Administrator,
4. Project Billing Manager,
5. Service usage admin

We have tried creating a new GCP org from scratch and then assigning folders and projects to it but still running into the same issue. The user who created is also an admin with access to admin console.

Any idea on what might be going on? Can we not assign the billing on Org level despite having a billing account on the org.

Also we are successfully able to attribute the subscription on the project level.